# Scraping Data from Facebook with Python

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I've been trying for several day now (unsuccessfully) to scrape cities from about 500 Facebook URLs. However, Facebook handles its data in a very strange way and I can't figure out what's going on under the hood to understand what I need to do.

Essentially the problem is that Facebook displays very different amounts of data depending on who is logged in, and what the privacy settings of the account are. For instance, try opening the following three links, both in a browser where you are logged into Facebook, and one where you are not:

[REDACTED LINKS DUE TO PRIVACY CONCERNS]

As you can see, Facebook loads the data in both cases for the first link, but only gets data for the second link if you are logged in (to ANY account). The third link displays city when you are logged in, but only displays other information when you are not.

The reason this is extremely problematic (and related to Python) is that when trying to scrape the page with Beautiful Soup or Mechanize, I cannot figure out how to get the program to "pretend" that I am logged into an account. This means that I can easily grab data off the first type of link (of which there are less than 10), but I cannot get city off the second or third type. So far I've tried a number of solutions with little success.

Here's some sample code that works correctly for the first type, but not for other types:

```
import mechanize
import re
import csv

user_info = []

fb_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/100004210542493'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.open(fb_url)
all_html = br.response().get_data()
print all_html

city = re.search('fsl fwb fcb">(.+?)</a></div><div class="aboutSubtitle fsm fwn fcg', all_html).group(1)

user_info = [fb_url, city]
print user_info
```

I also have a version that uses Beautiful Soup. If anyone has any ideas on how to get around this, I would be extremely grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Any luck? I've also tried things but failed.

Comment: Hello and good day dear cscanlin - many thanks for the question:  well i found out that we can scrape fb eg: see here: https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/
question: well can i scrape fb pages for a special key category - eg. 
female and  single  - is this possible!?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The **right** way to do this is to use the facebook API.  For various business, security, and privacy reasons they go out of their way to make scraping data tricky.

If you insist on scraping I would try to log in first using mechanize to submit the form.  I've never tried to do this with facebook, but alot of websites have easier to parse versions intended for mobile users at m.site.com.

Comment: as far as I can tell facebook does not allow you to access a user's city unless the user specifically allows you to. Do you know of any way around this or would I have to request access from all of them?

Comment: _“facebook does not allow you to access a user's city unless the user specifically allows you to.”_ – yes, it’s called _privacy_, please look it up. _“Do you know of any way around this”_ – so you are explicitly asking how to _violate_ a user’s privacy …?

Comment: It's hilarious and somewhat painful looking back at this question years later. Anyways I just realized I never accepted an answer, and this is the best answer to the question. So thanks for helping a misguided noobie!

Comment: @CBroe no, the user chose to expose this info so it's public. As a user you can see this so what's the difference in letting the api expose it? Facebook and privacy don't mix in case you haven't noticed.

Comment: @shinzou public via the website means available to an actual human being, that can click through a few sites and look at the info for a handful of people - no big deal. Publicly available via API would mean _shady app developer from shithole country of your choice_ could gather this data en masse, and (ab-)use it for whatever evil purpose they have in mind.

Comment: And that actual human can't abuse it? How is this different from a public forum? How is this different from keeping a log of an irc channel? Logging a twitter account? and so on. Also, how are they going to abuse PUBLIC information that users explicitly post on the internet??? if you write things you might regret maybe don't post them? it's only the poster's fault. @CBroe

Comment: @shinzou of course the human could do it, too - but it would take them much more time to gather that info for, say, a hundred thousand users, whereas (assuming user ids are known) an app doing this via API could do that in virtually no time at all ...

Answer (score 15):

You should look into using [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) by [Johannes Gorset](https://twitter.com/jgorset). He has done a brilliant job. I used it when I worked on a small Facebook app for a personal project.

Comment: Any luck on scraping from pages as well as groups in facebook? :-)

Comment: Did you compare facepy vs facebook-sdk? I'm trying to choose the best library at the moment..

Answer (score 4):

I think scraping data from facebook is illegal. It is there in the terms of using facebook. Every activity is registered with your login details, even when you use a bot to scrape. If caught, they can ban you from using facebook for your lifetime. If there is a potential threat to any asset that you may pose, they can penalize you further.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using selenium and Facebook API. I also had to scrape some similar data from list of testing Facebook accounts and selenium webdriver helped to emulate as real user and to scrape the required data.

Comment: For instagram there is very good lib called 'instaloader', is there something like that for facebook?
I came a cross this, but I could not find more information and more functions:
 https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/#description

Answer (score 0):

Try x2emails  [Facebook scraper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-scraper/ankhkmmolejpfiolijfcdjjmggdmfjfn) extension. Additionally, I had to scrape some similar data from test Facebook accounts to emulate a real user and to collect the needed information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).